# Can I play as player 1 using a controller?

Tags: really-big-sky

I tried playing Really Big Sky with a controller on my PC. When I turn my controller on I am prompted to press <kbd>A</kbd> on my controller to join, but then the controller ends up associated with player 2.

How can I associate the controller with player 1, then?

Comment: Just double checking here, but is this for the PC version? The game was also released on PSN for PS3/Vita under a slightly different name, Big Sky Infinity.

Comment: Good point! I'll edit my question.

Comment: You could try unplugging the keyboard and then connecting the controller.  Then plug the keyboard back in and that should end up being player 2.

Comment: @DavidStarkey A novel idea, but I would prefer something that doesn't have me crawling under my desk.